# Attempting to use Google Play Services, Google Sign in, keep getting an Error Code 10

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I am attempting to implement the google sign-in features as described here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

In the oncreate I have the following:

```
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

and I have the following functions, in the activity as well

```
public void signIn(View v) {
    System.out.println("WHAT!");
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 100);
 }
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        System.out.println("Success "+account);
      //  updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        System.out.println( "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        System.out.println( "ERROR "+e.getMessage());
       // updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

A button Click fires up the signIn and the user is properly presented with the accounts on the device,  however when I select an account the handle sign in result always returns and ERROR CODE of 10  which according to this:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#DEVELOPER_ERROR

is a Developer Error.. but I cannot see what I am doing incorrectly or have not configured... Any help would be appreciated.

Google Play Services is on the device and the latest version is installed.. I am utiilizing 11.6.0 versions of the play services in the build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, basically I didn't have the app configured at the google api level to accept google sign in...

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

I am not surprised by this, but it would have been nice if the links above back referenced this requirement from their documentation.  Once I properly did this and integrated the ids and keys, everything works as expected.